# Windows Phone 8 sdk installs only wp7 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I installed wp8 sdk.  I've never use It yet but It seems to be working. When I try to launch the emulator I see only wp7 emulator and not wp8. Why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can you tell you're getting the wp7 emulator?  So far as I know, the SDK only includes one version of the emulator, just in 4 different resolutions.

Comment: I've just added a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solve the problem.
I downloaded again and installed the SDK. I got a compatibility issue, but this time I could see all wp emulators.
The problem was that my copy of windows 8.1 was not updated and for the SDK I was still using dev preview of windows 8.1. I updated windows and the sdk, and now all works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have slat compatible system. Gen 3 iCore proc or later

you don't have to take my word for it (though I did have WP8 installed on Core 2 Duo device that wasn't SLAT compatible and WP8 emulator didn't show up.. only WP7)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devfish/archive/2012/11/06/are-you-slat-compatible-wp8-sdk-tip-01.aspx

since you both is SLAT compatible, follow this guide
http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator

Comment: So wp7 emulator works but 8 don't? Are you sure? Cause I'm using windows on a virtual machine as explained here http://windowsphonehacker.com/articles/running_the_windows_phone_8_emulator_in_a_virtual_machine_video-01-21-13 and the first time I tried without fix the problem and after the installation I saw errors. This time I didn't see any errors. Also, the first time the window in which you choose which emulator didn't work. This time works...

Comment: have a look at the link I posted

Comment: I've just added a picture. you can see that the tools says I have a slat compatible system...